# Grouping Collection in FormBuilder Symfony2

Tags: symfony

How can I change the order of displaying the collection, and group them by a category that is in the FooBar entity.

```
$builder
    ->add('foobar', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new FooBarType()
    ));
```

The query_builder only works for Entities, not Collections. So it is not about ordering the result, but about Grouping based on the category of the FooBarType, and show them in that order.

Like:

> [COLLECTION]
>
> Category One name  :  [list with that category]
>
> Category Two name   : [list with that category]

The view is now showing the collection, with the category name in front:

```
{% for db in edit_form.foobar %}
    <li>[Category: {{ db.foobar.vars.data.name }}] 
    {{ form_widget(db.value) }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to group this by category. So they are sorted by Category name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help:

```
{% set category = '' %}
{% for db in edit_form.foobar %}
    <li>
        {% set currentCategory = db.foobar.vars.data.category.name %}
        {% if category != currentCategory  %}
            <p>{{ currentCategory }}</p>
            {% set category = currentCategory %}
        {% endif %}                                
        {{ form_widget(db.value) }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

And order the Category in your Entity like Joao said.

Answer (score 0):

In your entity, on your oneToMany or ManyToMany annotation you can add this:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="FooBar")
 * @OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 */
private $foobar;
```

With this, when you loop foobar on a template, they are ordered and sorted by what you defined.

source:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-orderby

Comment: Yes, that is for ordering. My question was about GroupBy. The Collection I want to show is a list, and the list has multiple Categories where they are in.